# how to use jquery param to encode quotation or apostrophe in the get url?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery tooltip and using jquery param to prepare the parameters for the url.
My problem is that when the name has a quotation (") or an apostrophe (') the apartment is not received at the server side.

```
t = {};
t['building'] = building;
t['name'] = name;
t['apartment'] = apartment;
return sprintf("<div dir='rtl'><iframe class='map' alt='' src='http://127.0.0.1:9999/toolTip?%s'></iframe></div>", $.param(t, true));
```

How can I overcome this issue?
Thanks

Comment: `sprintf` is a PHP function **not** javascript...

Comment: ignore the sprintf, it is not the issue, it is derived from a js module I downloaded

Comment: `$.param()` encodes special characters in the parameters properly. The problem is probably in the database code on the server.